# In jmeter, How can manage the execution of thread groups

Tags: jmeter

There are 3 thread groups as threadGroup1, threadGroup2 & threadGroup3. now i need to execute the threadGroup1 - 1 time, threadGroup2 - 5 times & threadGroup3 - 10 times.

please suggest how can achieve above scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) documentation:

> **Loop Count**
>
> Number of times to perform the test case. Alternatively, "forever" can be selected causing the test to run until manually stopped.

So set the following Loop Counts:

- `threadGroup1` - 1
- `threadGroup2` - 5
- `threadGroup3` - 10

Also you can control whether JMeter will execute all Thread Groups at the same time or consecutively upside down using "Run Thread Groups Consecutively" checkbox at [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for comprehensive information on running thread groups or individual samplers with different distribution values.

Comment: Thank lot, then how can we maintain cookies across the all the thread group.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, i read your post "Using Different Thread Groups with a Different Number of Threads". i have one doubt suppose i have online shopping application, first thread group consist 20 user those have login related activities, second thread group consist 10 user those have select product activities, third thread group consist 5 user those have payment related activities. then how can we maintain the same cookies from first to third thread group. Is this possible with cookies manager?. please help.

Comment: It is possible to pass cookies between thread groups, see [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for example. However ideally thread group should represent an isolated group of virtual users that's why JMeter Variables are local to Thread Group and Cookie Manager, Header Manager, etc. scope is limited to current Thread Group only

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the loop count property.

Setting the loop count to 10 will execute the threadgroup 10 times.
`-1` is forever.

[image]